# infinite scroll - how to scrape website

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am trying to download a page which has infinite scroll when obtaining the resutls. I have found the url of the ajax source. When i put it on a browser it works fine and it returns the json format data. But when i try to download the page through wget, i get Access denied message. Do you have any idea why is this happening?

the command i am using is:

```
wget --cookies=on --load-cookies=cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --user-agent=Firefox \
    "https://www.somesite.com/ajax/pagelet/generic.php/pagination?data={"collection_token":"...","cursor":"...","tab_key":"....","profile_id":"...","overview":"...","ftid":"null","sk":"..."}&__user=...&__a=1"
```

Comment: Unable to answer with only the data provided.

Comment: the file that is being saved has the following:
for (;;);{"__ar":1,"error":1357001,"errorSummary":"Niet aangemeld","errorDescription":"Meld je aan om door te gaan.","payload":{"__dialog":{"title":{"__html":"Niet aangemeld"},"body":{"__html":"Meld je aan om door te gaan."},"buttons":[{"name":"login","label":"Aanmelden","handler":"goURI(\"http:\\\/\\\/www.facebook.com\\\/login.php\", true);"}],"modal":true,"onloadRegister":["setInterval(function () {\n        if (getCookie(\"c_user\") || getCookie(\"csm\")) {\n          window.location.reload();\n        }}, 5000);"]}},"js":["kQ5UI","PIiAz"]

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to go about it.

One is to render the page's DOM tree in webkit using a library like PhantomJs and scroll the page before doing evaluate.

Second method is to find out the pattern in the background Ajax call and call the actual AJAX ends points

Answer (score 0):

For one, you've got a quoting problem. The URL contains double quotes so you'll need to either escape them with backslashes or surround the URL with single quotes instead.

```
wget --cookies=on --load-cookies=cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --user-agent=Firefox \
    'https://www.somesite.com/ajax/pagelet/generic.php/pagination?data={"collection_token":"...","cursor":"...","tab_key":"....","profile_id":"...","overview":"...","ftid":"null","sk":"..."}&__user=...&__a=1'
```

Comment: i tried both with backslashes i get error 500 internal server error

Answer (score -1):

When using wget, you are sending a GET request to the page, but AJAX uses a POST request.
As you are using python, using [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib2.html) to create a POST request usually does the trick. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: AJAX can also do GET requests

Comment: Thank you for quick responses, i ve also tried the following, but i get a "No JSON object could be decoded: line 1 column 0 (char 0)" response. 
import simplejson
import urllib
import urllib2

params ={"collection_token":"...","cursor":"...","tab_key":"...","profile_id":"...","overview":"...","ftid":"...","sk":"..."}
url = 'https://www.somesite.com/ajax/pagelet/generic.php/...?__user=541551551&__a=1'
data = urllib.urlencode(params)
response = urllib2.urlopen(url, data)
json_response = simplejson.loads(response.read())